# Full Text Search Mysql Not working with & symbol Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, full-text-search

I am trying to find these words on full text search mode.

> 'a&w' 'b&w' 'b & w'

The query return empty results for those words.

My query

```
$input = Input::get('term');
$results = Name_tag::where('status', 2)
    ->take(5)
    ->groupBy('brand_id')
    ->whereRaw(
        "MATCH (keyword) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
        $this->fullTextFullTerm($input)
    )
    ->get();

protected function fullTextFullTerm($input)
{
    $reservedSymbols = ['-', '+', '<', '>', '@', '(', ')', '~'];
    $input= str_replace($reservedSymbols, '', $input);

    $words = '"'.$input.'"';
    return $words;
}
```

Some words on my table

a&w
b&w
a & w
b & w

....

Other search word without & is working properly. Any idea whats wrong ? Why full text search cant find word containing & symbol in it?

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to search for? Show output from `dump($this->fullTextFullTerm($input));`

Comment: I am trying to find b&w or a&w, but the results is empty. If I try with different phrase without & symbol, it works fine. The output of the dump ""a&w""

Comment: Probably it's too short. What is `innodb_ft_min_token_size`?

Comment: innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2, the problem seem occur when there is & symbol

Comment: Try replacing `get()` with `dd()` to see the query that's generated. Does it look ok? I don't have much experience with FTS so I'm not certain about how it handles quotes.

Comment: I m using toSql(), the query is "select * from `name_tags` where `status` = ? and MATCH (keyword) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) group by `brand_id` limit 5"

Comment: Use `dd()` and edit your question to include the exact output.